# I got error when I install slc command line tool

Tags: node.js, npm, strongloop, loopback

It maybe stupid question. but, I couldn't find solution .I tried to install loopback, so that following link. [enter link description here](https://javabeat.net/loopback-mysql/)

when I tried `npm install -g strongloop` to instal slc command line tool I got this error

```
npm WARN deprecated swagger-ui@2.2.10: No longer maintained, please upgrade to swagger-ui@3.
npm WARN deprecated nodemailer@2.7.2: All versions below 4.0.1 of Nodemailer are deprecated. See https://nodemailer.com/status/
npm WARN deprecated mailcomposer@4.0.1: This project is unmaintained
npm WARN deprecated socks@1.1.9: If using 2.x branch, please upgrade to at least 2.1.6 to avoid a serious bug with socket data flow and an import issue introduced in 2.1.0
npm WARN deprecated buildmail@4.0.1: This project is unmaintained
npm WARN deprecated gulp-util@3.0.8: gulp-util is deprecated - replace it, following the guidelines at https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5
npm WARN deprecated ejs@1.0.0: Critical security bugs fixed in 2.5.5
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@3.0.11: please upgrade to graceful-fs 4 for compatibility with current and future versions of Node.js
npm WARN deprecated hoek@2.16.3: The major version is no longer supported. Please update to 4.x or newer
npm WARN deprecated sprintf@0.1.5: The sprintf package is deprecated in favor of sprintf-js.
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead
npm WARN deprecated swagger-ui@2.0.24: No longer maintained, please upgrade to swagger-ui@3.
npm WARN deprecated connect@2.30.2: connect 2.x series is deprecated
npm WARN deprecated swagger-client@2.0.36: No longer maintained, please upgrade to swagger-client@3.
npm WARN deprecated coffee-script@1.6.3: CoffeeScript on NPM has moved to "coffeescript" (no hyphen)
npm WARN deprecated sprintf@0.1.1: The sprintf package is deprecated in favor of sprintf-js.
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
/usr/local/bin/lb-ng -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/loopback-sdk-angular-cli/bin/lb-ng.js
/usr/local/bin/slc -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/strongloop/bin/slc.js

> heapdump@0.3.9 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/heapdump
> node-gyp rebuild

make: Entering directory '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/heapdump/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/addon/src/heapdump.o
In file included from ../src/heapdump.cc:17:0:
../src/compat-inl.h: In static member function ‘static void compat::CpuProfiler::StartCpuProfiling(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::String>)’:
../src/compat-inl.h:300:34: warning: ‘v8::CpuProfiler* v8::Isolate::GetCpuProfiler()’ is deprecated: CpuProfiler should be created with CpuProfiler::New call. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   return isolate->GetCpuProfiler()->StartProfiling(title, record_samples);
                                  ^
In file included from /home/arebhy/.node-gyp/10.8.0/include/node/v8.h:26:0,
                 from /home/arebhy/.node-gyp/10.8.0/include/node/node.h:63,
                 from ../src/heapdump.cc:15:
/home/arebhy/.node-gyp/10.8.0/include/node/v8.h:7399:30: note: declared here
                 CpuProfiler* GetCpuProfiler());
                              ^
/home/arebhy/.node-gyp/10.8.0/include/node/v8config.h:324:3: note: in definition of macro ‘V8_DEPRECATED’
   declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
   ^
In file included from ../src/heapdump.cc:17:0:
../src/compat-inl.h: In static member function ‘static const v8::CpuProfile* compat::CpuProfiler::StopCpuProfiling(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::String>)’:
../src/compat-inl.h:310:34: warning: ‘v8::CpuProfiler* v8::Isolate::GetCpuProfiler()’ is deprecated: CpuProfiler should be created with CpuProfiler::New call. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   return isolate->GetCpuProfiler()->StopProfiling(title);
                                  ^
In file included from /home/arebhy/.node-gyp/10.8.0/include/node/v8.h:26:0,
                 from /home/arebhy/.node-gyp/10.8.0/include/node/node.h:63,
                 from ../src/heapdump.cc:15:
/home/arebhy/.node-gyp/10.8.0/include/node/v8.h:7399:30: note: declared here
                 CpuProfiler* GetCpuProfiler());
                              ^
/home/arebhy/.node-gyp/10.8.0/include/node/v8config.h:324:3: note: in definition of macro ‘V8_DEPRECATED’
   declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
   ^
../src/heapdump.cc: In function ‘compat::ReturnType {anonymous}::WriteSnapshot(const ArgumentType&)’:
../src/heapdump.cc:106:46: warning: ‘v8::String::Utf8Value::Utf8Value(v8::Local<v8::Value>)’ is deprecated: Use Isolate version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     String::Utf8Value filename_string(args[0]);
                                              ^
In file included from /home/arebhy/.node-gyp/10.8.0/include/node/v8.h:26:0,
                 from /home/arebhy/.node-gyp/10.8.0/include/node/node.h:63,
                 from ../src/heapdump.cc:15:
/home/arebhy/.node-gyp/10.8.0/include/node/v8.h:2852:28: note: declared here
                   explicit Utf8Value(Local<v8::Value> obj));
                            ^
/home/arebhy/.node-gyp/10.8.0/include/node/v8config.h:324:3: note: in definition of macro ‘V8_DEPRECATED’
   declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
   ^
../src/heapdump.cc: In function ‘void {anonymous}::InvokeCallback(const char*)’:
../src/heapdump.cc:144:32: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> node::MakeCallback(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::Function>, int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*)’ is deprecated: Use MakeCallback(..., async_context) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                      argc, argv);
                                ^
In file included from ../src/heapdump.cc:15:0:
/home/arebhy/.node-gyp/10.8.0/include/node/node.h:172:50: note: declared here
                 NODE_EXTERN v8::Local<v8::Value> MakeCallback(
                                                  ^
/home/arebhy/.node-gyp/10.8.0/include/node/node.h:88:42: note: in definition of macro ‘NODE_DEPRECATED’
     __attribute__((deprecated(message))) declarator
                                          ^
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/addon.node
  COPY Release/addon.node
make: Leaving directory '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/heapdump/build'

> modern-syslog@1.1.4 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/modern-syslog
> node-gyp rebuild

make: Entering directory '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/modern-syslog/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/core/core.o
In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:190:0,
                 from ../core.cc:2:
../../nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h: In function ‘Nan::Maybe<bool> Nan::ForceSet(v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::PropertyAttribute)’:
../../nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:88:15: error: ‘class v8::Object’ has no member named ‘ForceSet’
   return obj->ForceSet(GetCurrentContext(), key, value, attribs);
               ^
In file included from ../core.cc:2:0:
../../nan/nan.h: In function ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::MakeCallback(v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::Function>, int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*)’:
../../nan/nan.h:817:60: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> node::MakeCallback(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::Function>, int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*)’ is deprecated: Use MakeCallback(..., async_context) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
         v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), target, func, argc, argv);
                                                            ^
In file included from ../core.cc:1:0:
/home/arebhy/.node-gyp/10.8.0/include/node/node.h:172:50: note: declared here
                 NODE_EXTERN v8::Local<v8::Value> MakeCallback(
                                                  ^
/home/arebhy/.node-gyp/10.8.0/include/node/node.h:88:42: note: in definition of macro ‘NODE_DEPRECATED’
     __attribute__((deprecated(message))) declarator
                                          ^
In file included from ../core.cc:2:0:
../../nan/nan.h: In function ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::MakeCallback(v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::String>, int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*)’:
../../nan/nan.h:831:62: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> node::MakeCallback(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::String>, int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*)’ is deprecated: Use MakeCallback(..., async_context) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
         v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), target, symbol, argc, argv);
                                                              ^
In file included from ../core.cc:1:0:
/home/arebhy/.node-gyp/10.8.0/include/node/node.h:165:50: note: declared here
                 NODE_EXTERN v8::Local<v8::Value> MakeCallback(
                                                  ^
/home/arebhy/.node-gyp/10.8.0/include/node/node.h:88:42: note: in definition of macro ‘NODE_DEPRECATED’
     __attribute__((deprecated(message))) declarator
                                          ^
In file included from ../core.cc:2:0:
../../nan/nan.h: In function ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::MakeCallback(v8::Local<v8::Object>, const char*, int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*)’:
../../nan/nan.h:845:62: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> node::MakeCallback(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::Object>, const char*, int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*)’ is deprecated: Use MakeCallback(..., async_context) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
         v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), target, method, argc, argv);
                                                              ^
In file included from ../core.cc:1:0:
/home/arebhy/.node-gyp/10.8.0/include/node/node.h:158:50: note: declared here
                 NODE_EXTERN v8::Local<v8::Value> MakeCallback(
                                                  ^
/home/arebhy/.node-gyp/10.8.0/include/node/node.h:88:42: note: in definition of macro ‘NODE_DEPRECATED’
     __attribute__((deprecated(message))) declarator
                                          ^
In file included from ../core.cc:2:0:
../../nan/nan.h: In member function ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::Callback::Call_(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::Object>, int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*) const’:
../../nan/nan.h:1453:5: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> node::MakeCallback(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::Function>, int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*)’ is deprecated: Use MakeCallback(..., async_context) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     ));
     ^
In file included from ../core.cc:1:0:
/home/arebhy/.node-gyp/10.8.0/include/node/node.h:172:50: note: declared here
                 NODE_EXTERN v8::Local<v8::Value> MakeCallback(
                                                  ^
/home/arebhy/.node-gyp/10.8.0/include/node/node.h:88:42: note: in definition of macro ‘NODE_DEPRECATED’
     __attribute__((deprecated(message))) declarator
                                          ^
core.target.mk:103: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/core/core.o' failed
make: *** [Release/obj.target/core/core.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/modern-syslog/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:238:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.15.0-33-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/modern-syslog
gyp ERR! node -v v10.8.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 

> sqlite3@3.1.4 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/sqlite3
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
node-pre-gyp verb cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node',
node-pre-gyp verb cli   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/sqlite3/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp',
node-pre-gyp verb cli   'install',
node-pre-gyp verb cli   '--fallback-to-build' ]
node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@0.6.28
node-pre-gyp info using node@10.8.0 | linux | x64
node-pre-gyp verb command install []
node-pre-gyp info check checked for "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v64-linux-x64/node_sqlite3.node" (not found)
node-pre-gyp http GET https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v3.1.4/node-v64-linux-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp http 403 https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v3.1.4/node-v64-linux-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download: https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v3.1.4/node-v64-linux-x64.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for sqlite3@3.1.4 and node@10.8.0 (node-v64 ABI) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
node-pre-gyp http 403 status code downloading tarball https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v3.1.4/node-v64-linux-x64.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp verb command build [ 'rebuild' ]
node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download: https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v3.1.4/node-v64-linux-x64.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for sqlite3@3.1.4 and node@10.8.0 (node-v64 ABI) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
node-pre-gyp http Connection closed while downloading tarball file 
node-pre-gyp verb command build [ 'rebuild' ]
make: Entering directory '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/sqlite3/build'
make: Entering directory '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/sqlite3/build'
  ACTION deps_sqlite3_gyp_action_before_build_target_unpack_sqlite_dep Release/obj/gen/sqlite-autoconf-3090100/sqlite3.c
  ACTION deps_sqlite3_gyp_action_before_build_target_unpack_sqlite_dep Release/obj/gen/sqlite-autoconf-3090100/sqlite3.c
  TOUCH Release/obj.target/deps/action_before_build.stamp
  TOUCH Release/obj.target/deps/action_before_build.stamp
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/sqlite3/gen/sqlite-autoconf-3090100/sqlite3.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/sqlite3/gen/sqlite-autoconf-3090100/sqlite3.o
  AR(target) Release/obj.target/deps/sqlite3.a
  COPY Release/sqlite3.a
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/node_sqlite3/src/database.o
  AR(target) Release/obj.target/deps/sqlite3.a
  COPY Release/sqlite3.a
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/node_sqlite3/src/database.o
In file included from ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:190:0,
                 from ../src/database.h:10,
                 from ../src/database.cc:4:
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h: In function ‘Nan::Maybe<bool> Nan::ForceSet(v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::PropertyAttribute)’:
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:88:15: error: ‘class v8::Object’ has no member named ‘ForceSet’
   return obj->ForceSet(GetCurrentContext(), key, value, attribs);
               ^
In file included from ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:190:0,
                 from ../src/database.h:10,
                 from ../src/database.cc:4:
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h: In function ‘Nan::Maybe<bool> Nan::ForceSet(v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::PropertyAttribute)’:
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:88:15: error: ‘class v8::Object’ has no member named ‘ForceSet’
   return obj->ForceSet(GetCurrentContext(), key, value, attribs);
               ^
In file included from ../src/database.h:10:0,
                 from ../src/database.cc:4:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::MakeCallback(v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::Function>, int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*)’:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:817:60: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> node::MakeCallback(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::Function>, int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*)’ is deprecated: Use MakeCallback(..., async_context) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
         v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), target, func, argc, argv);
                                                            ^
In file included from ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:47:0,
                 from ../src/database.h:10,
                 from ../src/database.cc:4:
/home/arebhy/.node-gyp/10.8.0/include/node/node.h:172:50: note: declared here
                 NODE_EXTERN v8::Local<v8::Value> MakeCallback(
                                                  ^
/home/arebhy/.node-gyp/10.8.0/include/node/node.h:88:42: note: in definition of macro ‘NODE_DEPRECATED’
     __attribute__((deprecated(message))) declarator
                                          ^
In file included from ../src/database.h:10:0,
                 from ../src/database.cc:4:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::MakeCallback(v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::String>, int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*)’:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:831:62: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> node::MakeCallback(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::String>, int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*)’ is deprecated: Use MakeCallback(..., async_context) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
         v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), target, symbol, argc, argv);
                                                              ^
In file included from ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:47:0,
                 from ../src/database.h:10,
                 from ../src/database.cc:4:
/home/arebhy/.node-gyp/10.8.0/include/node/node.h:165:50: note: declared here
                 NODE_EXTERN v8::Local<v8::Value> MakeCallback(
                                                  ^
/home/arebhy/.node-gyp/10.8.0/include/node/node.h:88:42: note: in definition of macro ‘NODE_DEPRECATED’
     __attribute__((deprecated(message))) declarator
                                          ^
In file included from ../src/database.h:10:0,
                 from ../src/database.cc:4:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::MakeCallback(v8::Local<v8::Object>, const char*, int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*)’:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:845:62: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> node::MakeCallback(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::Object>, const char*, int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*)’ is deprecated: Use MakeCallback(..., async_context) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
         v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), target, method, argc, argv);
                                                              ^
In file included from ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:47:0,
                 from ../src/database.h:10,
                 from ../src/database.cc:4:
/home/arebhy/.node-gyp/10.8.0/include/node/node.h:158:50: note: declared here
                 NODE_EXTERN v8::Local<v8::Value> MakeCallback(
                                                  ^
/home/arebhy/.node-gyp/10.8.0/include/node/node.h:88:42: note: in definition of macro ‘NODE_DEPRECATED’
     __attribute__((deprecated(message))) declarator
                                          ^
In file included from ../src/database.h:10:0,
                 from ../src/database.cc:4:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In member function ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::Callback::Call_(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::Object>, int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*) const’:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:1463:5: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> node::MakeCallback(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::Function>, int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*)’ is deprecated: Use MakeCallback(..., async_context) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     ));
     ^
In file included from ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:47:0,
                 from ../src/database.h:10,
                 from ../src/database.cc:4:
/home/arebhy/.node-gyp/10.8.0/include/node/node.h:172:50: note: declared here
                 NODE_EXTERN v8::Local<v8::Value> MakeCallback(
                                                  ^
/home/arebhy/.node-gyp/10.8.0/include/node/node.h:88:42: note: in definition of macro ‘NODE_DEPRECATED’
     __attribute__((deprecated(message))) declarator
                                          ^
In file included from ../src/database.h:10:0,
                 from ../src/database.cc:4:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::MakeCallback(v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::Function>, int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*)’:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:817:60: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> node::MakeCallback(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::Function>, int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*)’ is deprecated: Use MakeCallback(..., async_context) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
         v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), target, func, argc, argv);
                                                            ^
In file included from ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:47:0,
                 from ../src/database.h:10,
                 from ../src/database.cc:4:
/home/arebhy/.node-gyp/10.8.0/include/node/node.h:172:50: note: declared here
                 NODE_EXTERN v8::Local<v8::Value> MakeCallback(
                                                  ^
/home/arebhy/.node-gyp/10.8.0/include/node/node.h:88:42: note: in definition of macro ‘NODE_DEPRECATED’
     __attribute__((deprecated(message))) declarator
                                          ^
In file included from ../src/database.h:10:0,
                 from ../src/database.cc:4:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::MakeCallback(v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::String>, int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*)’:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:831:62: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> node::MakeCallback(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::String>, int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*)’ is deprecated: Use MakeCallback(..., async_context) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
         v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), target, symbol, argc, argv);
                                                              ^
In file included from ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:47:0,
                 from ../src/database.h:10,
                 from ../src/database.cc:4:
/home/arebhy/.node-gyp/10.8.0/include/node/node.h:165:50: note: declared here
                 NODE_EXTERN v8::Local<v8::Value> MakeCallback(
                                                  ^
/home/arebhy/.node-gyp/10.8.0/include/node/node.h:88:42: note: in definition of macro ‘NODE_DEPRECATED’
     __attribute__((deprecated(message))) declarator
                                          ^
In file included from ../src/database.h:10:0,
                 from ../src/database.cc:4:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::MakeCallback(v8::Local<v8::Object>, const char*, int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*)’:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:845:62: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> node::MakeCallback(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::Object>, const char*, int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*)’ is deprecated: Use MakeCallback(..., async_context) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
         v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), target, method, argc, argv);
                                                              ^
In file included from ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:47:0,
                 from ../src/database.h:10,
                 from ../src/database.cc:4:
/home/arebhy/.node-gyp/10.8.0/include/node/node.h:158:50: note: declared here
                 NODE_EXTERN v8::Local<v8::Value> MakeCallback(
                                                  ^
/home/arebhy/.node-gyp/10.8.0/include/node/node.h:88:42: note: in definition of macro ‘NODE_DEPRECATED’
     __attribute__((deprecated(message))) declarator
                                          ^
In file included from ../src/database.h:10:0,
                 from ../src/database.cc:4:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In member function ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::Callback::Call_(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::Object>, int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*) const’:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:1463:5: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> node::MakeCallback(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::Function>, int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*)’ is deprecated: Use MakeCallback(..., async_context) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     ));
     ^
```

So first line of error said that upgrade to swagger-ui@3. So how can I resolve this error.
I followed this link also. I got same error  [enter link description here](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Installation.html)

Could you please anyone help me to solve this problem

Comment: Something could've went wrong. I recommend uninstalling what've installed and running `npm install -g loopback-cli` as described here: https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Installation.html#install-loopback-cli-tool
Best of luck!